# Which URL(s) do I choose for one product with different colours?

Tags: seo, url, canonical-url, website-promotion

I read that it is best practices that if you have a product that comes in 3 colours to have one URL for the product, and then to have a dropdown with all the colours that it comes in?

For example if I had a shirt that comes in 3 colours, grey, green and blue then you will have to have 1 URL like:

`www.example.com/product/1001/brand-shirt` instead of:

```
www.example.com/product/1001/brand-shirt-grey
www.example.com/product/1001/brand-shirt-green
www.example.com/product/1001/brand-shirt-blue
```

So now my question is, if you are using the one URL for the product, how do you promote the green shirt? How do you direct a customer to the green shirt? How do you share just the green on Facebook, Twitter, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Often you'll see a query string appended to the URL. So `/product/1001/brand-shirt` may be the canonical URL, but `/product/1001/brand-shirt?colour=green` may be used to link directly to that version. Then you can use the [URL Parameters](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-url-parameters) feature in Search Console as explained [here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/improved-handling-of-urls-with.html).

Alternatively some JavaScript-y bits may be used, like `/product/1001/brand-shirt#blue` .

`<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/product/1001/brand-shirt">` should be in between the `<head></head>` tags of your page either way.

Answer (score 1):

I would go also for one main URL. Why? Because in general, people don't search for a "green tee-shirt" on Google, they search a "tee-shirt" or a "Calvin Klein tee-shirt", whatever the colour; they only choose the colour when they see the tee-shirt on the website. I think that is the main reason why one main URL with a drop down list for the colour is the best option. Moreover, imagine that tomorrow, you want to share a "Calvin Klein tee-shirt" (whatever the colour), you can only do it easily if you have one main URL with all colour accessible with a drop down list (you're not going to share one URL by colour).

Then, you can manage the colour of the tee-shirt with URL parameters (`?colour=green`) or an id (`#green`). You just need to put the `"rel=canonical"` tag (`http://www.example.com/product/1001/brand-shirt`) on all versions of the main URL to avoid duplicate content issues.

Therefore, by managing URL parameters or an id for the colour, you can easily share the "green tee-shirt" (if you really want to).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is imho:

- to have only one URL,
- to show all product variants as images + additional descriptions,
- to let the buyer select, which variant he buys, only at the checkout routine, i.e. as a checkbox value.

more URLs == more troubles, independently of how the URLs are built, with parameter or not.

The way through anchor, like `example.com/product#variant` is good too, because the anchor value isn't transferred with URL.